# How to quickly find and replace many items on a list without replacing previously replaced items in BASH?

Tags: perl, bash, optimization, replace, sed

I want to perform about many find and replace operations on some text. I have a UTF-8 CSV file containing what to find (in the first column) and what to replace it with (in the second column), arranged from longest to shortest.

E.g.:

```
orange,fruit2
carrot,vegetable1
apple,fruit3
pear,fruit4
ink,item1
table,item2
```

Original file:

```
"I like to eat apples and carrots"
```

Resulting output file:

```
"I like to eat fruit3s and vegetable1s."
```

However, I want to ensure that if one part of text has already been replaced, that it doesn't mess with text that was already replaced. In other words, I don't want it to appear like this (it matched "table" from within vegetable1):

```
"I like to eat fruit3s and vegeitem21s."
```

Currently, I am using this method which is quite slow, because I have to do the whole find and replace twice:

(1) Convert the CSV to three files, e.g.:

```
a.csv     b.csv   c.csv
orange    0001    fruit2
carrot    0002    vegetable1
apple     0003    fruit3
pear      0004    fruit4
ink       0005    item1
table     0006    item 2
```

(2) Then, replace all items from `a.csv` in `file.txt` with the matching column in `b.csv`, using `ZZZ` around the words to make sure there is no mistake later in matching the numbers:

```
a=1
b=`wc -l < ./a.csv`
while [ $a -le $b ]
do
    for i in `sed -n "$a"p ./b.csv`; do
        for j in `sed -n "$a"p ./a.csv`; do
            sed -i "s/$i/ZZZ$j\ZZZ/g" ./file.txt
            echo "Instances of '"$i"' replaced with '"ZZZ$j\ZZZ"' ("$a"/"$b")."
            a=`expr $a + 1`
            done
    done
done
```

(3) Then running this same script again, but to replace `ZZZ0001ZZZ` with `fruit2` from `c.csv`.

Running the first replacement takes about 2 hours, but as I must run this code twice to avoid editing the already replaced items, it takes twice as long. Is there a more efficient way to run a find and replace that does not perform replacements on text already replaced?

Comment: What language or technology are you looking to do this in?

Comment: Within Linux. I don't have any particular language in mind, but I need to make sure that can support UTF-8.

Comment: how many lines are in each file?

Comment: The files to edit and the lists are each 100,000 lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be to do a two-phase replace:

```
phase 1:

s/orange/@@1##/
s/carrot/@@2##/
...

phase 2:
s/@@1##/fruit2/
s/@@2##/vegetable1/
...
```

The @@1## markers should be chosen so that they don't appear in the original text or the replacements of course.

Here's a proof-of-concept implementation in perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#

my $repls = $ARGV[0];
die ("first parameter must be the replacement list file") unless defined ($repls);
my $tmpFmt = "@@@%d###";

open(my $replsFile, "<", $repls) || die("$!: $repls");
shift;

my @replsList;

my $i = 0;
while (<$replsFile>) {
    chomp;
    my ($from, $to) = /\"([^\"]*)\",\"([^\"]*)\"/;
    if (defined($from) && defined($to)) {
        push(@replsList, [$from, sprintf($tmpFmt, ++$i), $to]);
    }
}

while (<>) {
    foreach my $r (@replsList) {
        s/$r->[0]/$r->[1]/g;
    }
    foreach my $r (@replsList) {
        s/$r->[1]/$r->[2]/g;
    }
    print;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a perl solution which is doing the replacement in "one phase".

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
my %map = (
       orange => "fruit2",
       carrot => "vegetable1",
       apple  => "fruit3",
       pear   => "fruit4",
       ink    => "item1",
       table  => "item2",
);
my $repl_rx = '(' . join("|", map { quotemeta } keys %map) . ')';
my $str = "I like to eat apples and carrots";
$str =~ s{$repl_rx}{$map{$1}}g;
print $str, "\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

Tcl has a command to do exactly this: [`string map`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/string.htm#M38)

```
tclsh <<'END'
set map {
    "orange" "fruit2"
    "carrot" "vegetable1"
    "apple" "fruit3"
    "pear" "fruit4"
    "ink" "item1"
    "table" "item2"
}
set str "I like to eat apples and carrots"
puts [string map $map $str]
END
```

```
I like to eat fruit3s and vegetable1s
```

This is how to implement it in bash (requires bash v4 for the associative array)

```
declare -A map=(
    [orange]=fruit2
    [carrot]=vegetable1
    [apple]=fruit3
    [pear]=fruit4
    [ink]=item1
    [table]=item2
)
str="I like to eat apples and carrots"
echo "$str"
i=0
while (( i < ${#str} )); do
    matched=false
    for key in "${!map[@]}"; do
        if [[ ${str:$i:${#key}} = $key ]]; then
            str=${str:0:$i}${map[$key]}${str:$((i+${#key}))}
            ((i+=${#map[$key]}))
            matched=true
            break
        fi
    done
    $matched || ((i++))
done
echo "$str"
```

```
I like to eat apples and carrots
I like to eat fruit3s and vegetable1s
```

This will not be speedy.

Clearly, you may get different results if you order the map differently. In fact, I believe the order of `"${!map[@]}"` is unspecified, so you might want to specify the order of the keys explicitly:

```
keys=(orange carrot apple pear ink table)
# ...
    for key in "${keys[@]}"; do
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing it twice is probably *not* your problem.    If you managed to just do it once using your basic strategy,  it would still take you an hour,  right?     You probably need to use a different technology or tool.     Switching to Perl,  as above,  might make your code a lot faster (give it a try)

But continuing down the path of other posters,  the next step might be pipelining.   Write a little program that replaces two columns,  then run that program twice,  simultaneously.   The first run swaps out strings in column1 with strings in column2,  the next swaps out strings in column2 with strings in column3.

Your command line would be like this

```
cat input_file.txt | perl replace.pl replace_file.txt 1 2 | perl replace.pl replace_file.txt 2 3 > completely_replaced.txt
```

And replace.pl would be like this (similar to other solutions)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $replace_file = $ARGV[0];
my $before_replace_colnum = $ARGV[1] - 1;
my $after_replace_colnum = $ARGV[2] - 1;

open(REPLACEFILE, $replace_file) || die("couldn't open $replace_file: $!");

my @replace_pairs;

# read in the list of things to replace
while(<REPLACEFILE>) {
    chomp();

    my @cols = split /\t/, $_;
    my $to_replace = $cols[$before_replace_colnum];
    my $replace_with = $cols[$after_replace_colnum];

    push @replace_pairs, [$to_replace, $replace_with];
}

# read input from stdin, do swapping
while(<STDIN>) {
    # loop over all replacement strings
    foreach my $replace_pair (@replace_pairs) {
        my($to_replace,$replace_with) = @{$replace_pair};
        $_ =~ s/${to_replace}/${replace_with}/g;
    }
    print STDOUT $_;
}
```

Comment: `cat` is really useless, and only one perl should be enough.

Comment: two perls enable pipelining

Comment: You could implement the replacement as a subroutine and call it twice inside one perl. You do not really need the pipes at all.

Comment: that will be much slower, truey.    your approach will use only a single processor/core.

Comment: You may be right. I'm going to make some performance tests... But `cat` still not needed. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that most of your slowness is coming from creating so many sed commands, which each need to individually process the entire file. Some minor adjustments to your current process would speed this up a lot by running 1 sed per file per step.

```
a=1
b=`wc -l < ./a.csv`
while [ $a -le $b ]
do
    cmd=""
    for i in `sed -n "$a"p ./a.csv`; do
        for j in `sed -n "$a"p ./b.csv`; do
            cmd="$cmd ; s/$i/ZZZ${j}ZZZ/g"
            echo "Instances of '"$i"' replaced with '"ZZZ${j}ZZZ"' ("$a"/"$b")."
            a=`expr $a + 1`
        done
    done

    sed -i "$cmd" ./file.txt
done
```

Answer (score 1):

A bash+sed approach:

```
count=0
bigfrom=""
bigto=""

while IFS=, read from to; do
   read countmd5sum x < <(md5sum <<< $count)
   count=$(( $count + 1 ))
   bigfrom="$bigfrom;s/$from/$countmd5sum/g"
   bigto="$bigto;s/$countmd5sum/$to/g"
done < replace-list.csv

sed "${bigfrom:1}$bigto" input_file.txt
```

I have chosen md5sum, to get some unique token. But some other mechanism can also be used to generate such token; like reading from `/dev/urandom` or `shuf -n1 -i 10000000-20000000`

Answer (score 1):

A awk+sed approach:

```
awk -F, '{a[NR-1]="s/####"NR"####/"$2"/";print "s/"$1"/####"NR"####/"}; END{for (i=0;i<NR;i++)print a[i];}' replace-list.csv > /tmp/sed_script.sed
sed -f /tmp/sed_script.sed input.txt
```

A cat+sed+sed approach:

```
cat -n replace-list.csv | sed -rn 'H;g;s|(.*)\n *([0-9]+) *[^,]*,(.*)|\1\ns/####\2####/\3/|;x;s|.*\n *([0-9]+)[ \t]*([^,]+).*|s/\2/####\1####/|p;${g;s/^\n//;p}' > /tmp/sed_script.sed
sed -f /tmp/sed_script.sed input.txt
```

Mechanism:

1. Here, it first generates the sed script, using the csv as input file.
2. Then uses another sed instance to operate on input.txt

Notes:

1. The intermediate file generated - sed_script.sed can be re-used again, unless the input csv file changes.
2. `####<number>####` is chosen as some pattern, which is not present in the input file. Change this pattern if required.
3. `cat -n |` is not UUOC :)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'h;s/./&\\n/g;H;x;s/([^,]*),.*,(.*)/s|\1|\2|g/;$s/$/;s|\\n||g/' csv_file | sed -rf - original_file
```

Convert the `csv` file into a `sed` script. The trick here is to replace the substitution string with one which will not be re-substituted. In this case each character in the substitution string is replaced by itself and a `\n`. Finally once all substitutions have taken place the `\n`'s are removed leaving the finished string.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of cool answers here already.  I'm posting this because I'm taking a slightly different approach by making some large assumptions about the data to replace ( based on the sample data ):

1. Words to replace don't contain spaces
2. Words are replaced based on the longest, exactly matching prefix
3. Each word to replace is exactly represented in the csv

This a single pass, awk only answer with very little regex.

It reads the "repl.csv" file into an associative array ( see BEGIN{} ), then attempts to match on prefixes of each word when the length of the word is bound by key length limits, trying to avoid looking in the associative array whenever possible:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    while( getline repline < "repl.csv" ) {
        split( repline, replarr, "," )
        replassocarr[ replarr[1] ] = replarr[2]
            # set some bounds on the replace word sizes
        if( minKeyLen == 0 || length( replarr[1] ) < minKeyLen )
            minKeyLen = length( replarr[1] )
        if( maxKeyLen == 0 || length( replarr[1] ) > maxKeyLen )
            maxKeyLen = length( replarr[1] )
    }
    close( "repl.csv" )
}

{
    i = 1
    while( i <= NF ) { print_word( $i, i == NF ); i++ }
}

function print_word( w, end ) {
    wl = length( w )
    for( j = wl; j >= 0 && prefix_len_bound( wl, j ); j-- ) {
        key = substr( w, 1, j )
        wl = length( key )
        if( wl >= minKeyLen && key in replassocarr ) {
            printf( "%s%s%s", replassocarr[ key ],
                substr( w, j+1 ), !end ? " " : "\n" )
            return
        }
    }
    printf( "%s%s", w, !end ? " " : "\n" )
}

function prefix_len_bound( len, jlen ) {
    return len >= minKeyLen && (len <= maxKeyLen || jlen > maxKeylen)
}
```

Based on input like:

```
I like to eat apples and carrots
orange you glad to see me
Some people eat pears while others drink ink
```

It yields output like:

```
I like to eat fruit3s and vegetable1s
fruit2 you glad to see me
Some people eat fruit4s while others drink item1
```

Of course any "savings" of not looking the replassocarr go away when the words to be replaced goes to length=1 or if the average word length is much greater than the words to replace.

Comment: I noticed, but didn't edit the example that the print_word() loop should really be refactored so that only the substr()s that are bound by the max and min key lens are even looked at.  Right now, it wastes some time from the end of longer words.